# App crashes on closing modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I have a second view controller for another screen. This view controller has a close button that dimisses the view controller. On pressing this close button, the app crashes. It crashes with the following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
```

This is the method I use to close the view controller, in the second view controller's .m

```
- (IBAction)done {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The crash occurs at `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

The second view controller is presented using this method in my main view controller:

```
-(IBAction)switchViews {

    [self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

Code related to rotation in main view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I haven't been able to resolve this issue. I've looked up that error and tried various solutions, but nothing has worked. Why is this crash happening? What am I doing wrong?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the wrong thing. The value it expects is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, but you're returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`. Note the Mask part.

Comment: Thanks, the crash no longer occurs now. Wow, I can't believe something so small caused me so much grief and frustration. How did you figure out that was the problem? How did you know it was expecting `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`?

Comment: @SegaDude The return type is `UIInterfaceOrientation`, so it will want a value that begins with that. The mask part is a bit annoying since usually there aren't two similar enums, but usually it should have only one capitalized part after the type. These are so easy to get wrong, especially when the other method has the mask version.